# How to find the canonical transformation if given the new Hamiltonian we want?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

If we know the new Hamiltonian $H^{\prime}$ we want, and $H^{\prime} \neq 0$, how can we find the canonical transformations?

For example, we want to transform the $$H(p,q)=\frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}kq^2$$ to the $$H^{\prime}(P,Q) = P^2+Q^3.$$ Note the cubic power.

The 2nd type generating function $S(q,P,t)$ thus satisfies:

$\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial t} + H=H^{\prime}$ with $p=\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial q}$ and $Q=\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial P}$

However, I can not proceed further.

Comment: An odd-powered potential would not have any stationary states (unless it is the absolute value of said odd-power). For a given energy, one could easily approximate with a linear potential - to explore tunnelling etc... 

I think you actually want to represent an even-powered potential with an odd power - a pure math exercise of some kind. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\partial S/\partial t = 0$. In this case, the equation for the generating function is
$$
\frac1{2m}\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial q}\right)^2 + \frac12 kq^2 = P^2 + \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)^2.
$$
All terms of this equation are squares. Hence, it is natural to try quadratic ansatz for $S$:
$$
S(q,P) = \frac{A}2 P^2 + \frac{B}2 q^2 + C Pq.
$$
Coefficients $A$, $B$, $C$ should satisfy following system of equations
$$
B = 2m A,\quad \frac{B^2}{2m} + \frac{k}2 = C^2,\quad \frac{C^2}{2m} = 1 + A^2.
$$
These equations are compatible only if $k/m = 4$. In this case, we obtain a one-parameter family of solutions
$$
B = 2mA,\quad C = \sqrt{2m(1+A^2)}.
$$
$A=0$ gives generating function $S = \sqrt{2m}\, qP$.

I suppose it is impossible to transform $H$ into $H'$ without $k/m=4$ condition fulfilled. Otherwise, $H$ can be transformed into
$$
H' = \frac12 \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}(P^2+Q^2).
$$

Comment: The attempt of quadratic ansatz for S is very enlightening. However, for the cubic power of Q, just as i asked in the question, it may not work. And i guess that for a general form of H', there is no unified method to solve the partial differential equation of S.

Comment: @Liang, I've probably misunderstood you. I thought your question is how to find $S$ for the quadratic hamiltonian example.